# Twitter Authorization page in site user language

Tags: php, twitter

I have a multilingual site and also doing sigin up users with twitter accounts. Currently if site is in English, twitter authorization page is in English. But I want is site is another language example German, I want twitter authorization page in German Language. Any ideas for doing this. I am using twitteroauth plug-in in php. I have tried to passing lang variable to url..but didn't worked :(